# Android: AdMob Not Showing

Tags: admob

For some reason, I'm getting nothing while running my AdMob in test mode. Can anyone see anything blatantly wrong?

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


    <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/ad"
                           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                           ads:adSize="BANNER"
                           ads:adUnitId="AD_ID"
                           ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR,TEST_EMULATOR, DEVICE_ID"
                           ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>        

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@android:drawable/alert_light_frame" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

and then my activity doesn't have anything in it, since loadAdOnCreate is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured out what the issue was! I was running this on a 2.3 phone, which is below the necessary Android version for AdMob. When I ran it inside a 4.0 VM, it worked fine!

My tip to people trying to find out what's wrong with their AdMob: use it in a straight XML fashion (above code), since this factors out any problems with your Java. Then try it in VMs instead of physical devices, and read the LogCat to look for any problems. Hope this helps!

Comment: FYI, you can use AdMob with Android 1.5 and up.  This is determined by the `<uses-sdk minSdkVersion>` element in your manifest.  Also, because you specified `TEST_EMULATOR` in `ads:testDevices`, you will get test ads on the emulator.  On your actual device though, you will get live ads, and there isn't a 100% fill rate.  To get test ads on the device, you'll have to replace `DEVICE_ID` with your actual md5 hashed device ID that AdMob provides in LogCat when you try to make a request on the device.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify your

```
ads:adUnitId="AD_ID"
```

you can get it on your admob account.
Should look something like

```
ads:adUnitId="a123456ff123456"
```

Without your id, AdMob will not serve you any Ad